# Splitting Actions-on-Google intents between typescript files on Node.js

Tags: typescript, google-cloud-functions, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

In my `src/index.ts` file on firebase functions for my dialogflow + google actions I have code which looks like the below:

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import { dialogflow, Suggestions } from 'actions-on-google';

const app = dialogflow({debug: true})
app.intent('Default Welcome Intent', conv => {
conv.ask('Question')
});

exports.dialogflowFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

I would like to split each intent into its own TS file (as I intend to have quite a few), but am lost as to how to export each intent from seperate `.ts` files to interact with `app`

Any ideas would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one organization that seems sane to me as a TypeScript programmer to have a set of TypeScript files that each have access to the `app` to add their own intents.  I've avoided side effects outside `index.ts` and circular dependencies among modules.  (Maybe people familiar with Dialogflow or Actions on Google will have their own recommendations.)

```
// app.ts
import { dialogflow } from 'actions-on-google';

export function createApp() {
    return dialogflow({debug: true});
}
export type App = ReturnType<typeof createApp>;

// intent1.ts
import { App } from "./app";

export function addIntent1(app: App) {
    app.intent('Default Welcome Intent', conv => {
        conv.ask('Question')
    });        
}

// index.ts
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import { createApp } from './app';
import { addIntent1 } from './intent1';

const app = createApp();
addIntent1(app);

exports.dialogflowFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```